# Releasing Wear OS app with the mobile app in the same time in Google Play

Tags: android, wear-os, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I wonder how to create a release in the same time for my android apps for phone and watch
There is no reason to use these apps separately, but technically you can install only android app or only wear os app.
They have the same package and the same name of app.

I was trying this way:
-upload with the same version code - error during uploading.
-upload with the different version codes - when I sent link for internal testing, both links for mobile app and wear app indicates the same app in story (only mobile so I wasn't able to test my wear os app, in addition without icon and name of app)
-upload without testing, directly to production - only mobile app is in review, when I was trying to send the wear os app, it just disappears from the table "releases overview" after a few seconds.

Any tricks ? I was trying to find on the internet some tutorials but there is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**In short** (new way of submitting):

- create the .aab(s)
  *same package and sign. Different version code
- create a new app on console site
- fill all the forms
- in advance settings enable wear os format
  upload the screenshots
- go to production, select the countries
- create a new version on the phone track (“smartphones, tables and chrome os”)
- upload the companion (phone app) .aab
- create a new version on the wear os track (“only wear os”)
- upload the watchface/watch app .aab
- enable the wear os distribution (on the advanced tab)
- send to review

**Observations**:

- there will always be only one link for both apps (watch app / watch face, and phone app)
- Sometimes you can "view" both apps on the phone playstore... other times you can only see the phone app on the phone playstore, and the watch app on the watch playstore...

**Extra**

- There are a lot of "info" on the samsung developers forum [like this for example](https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/google-play-wear-os-companion-app/18400/99)... those are more about watch face, but the process is pretty much the same.